# What are the ways to store array data on a local drive?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, oop, serialization

I want to store information about up to 1000 streets (the name, the ID and a short info, up to 500 characters). The right thing to do, seems to be to create class `Street` with three needed fields and create a `List` or an `array` of them. However,  I need to store (and edit, from time to time) all this data on user's computer. What are the ways? Storing such big arrays in `.txt` files seems to be inconvenient.

Comment: Who down voted the OP please leave some comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try SQLite (it also stores in local drive)? It allows you to do more than just store data.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why to save in txt. format and not xml ?
2. For best searching, etc. you can use B-tree ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree))

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1789/Object-Serialization-using-C

The link above provides a great, straight forward, example of how to serialize your data.

Also, if you need to make the file human readable, for some reason, feel free to insert a delimiter between serialized fields. As long as you remember to skip these delimiter values on deserialization.